# Self-Contained .Net Core Library missing .NET Core Runtime files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core-2.0

I am trying to publish my self-contained .NET Core Library for my Electron/Edge Application.

After publishing, my dll is located in the Publish output. However, it is missing all of the .NET Core Runtime files that .NET Core needs to be self-contained.

When publishing the same exact project as a Console App with the OutputType set to "Exe". It works fine, and all .NET Core Runtime files are located in the Publish folder output.

I am unsure as to why I am unable to make a self-contained library, so I can invoke the methods from my electron app via Edge. If someone could enlighten me as to why the .NET Core Runtime dependencies only show up in the publish output if it is a Console App that would be great.

Any information on how I can achieve my goal would also be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your publishing command? Besides, what is your target framework? I have an example where self-contained deployment definitely contains all dependencies, https://github.com/lextm/restructuredtext-antlr/blob/master/dist.server.bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the --self-contained argument to your publish, it will create the runtime files with your library. This is solved, thank you.

Comment: I suggest to mark your own post as answer to indicate that the question was solved.